# Positioning copyright footer to the bottom of Angular / C# application using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-4

I am struggling to use sticky-footer-wrapper from bootstrap so that the footer stays on the bottom of the page. However, it just appears right after the page content ends. Here is my `Index.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>XXXX</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="/Content/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="d-flex flex-column sticky-footer-wrapper">

            <app-root></app-root>

        <footer class="container-fluid w-100 bg-info text-light py-3">
            <div id="copyright">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.company.net/"><img src="/Content/img/xxxlogo_footer.png" alt="xxx Footer Logo" /></a>
                <span>xx.com is the global source of information about and access to services provided by the xxx companies.</span>
                <span class="pull-right copyright">&copy; 2019 xxxgroup Inc.</span>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/client/runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/client/polyfills.js"></script>
    @if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/client/styles.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/client/vendor.js"></script>
    }
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/client/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For the component template it is not working I am trying to add spacing/padding at the bottom by wrapping the contents it in a container

```
<div class="container mb-3 pb-3" ></div>
```

But still it is not working. Please guide.

Comment: Why you put whole script and css inside your index.cshtml but not layout.cshtml ?

Comment: Tony, honestly, I followed some sample tutorial to set up the project. So are you suggesting the footer from layout.cshtml should be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited after taking in the comments**

Add `vh-100` to the outer div to make it stretch to the viewport size initially and then `mb-auto` in the first element so it pushes the `footer` to the bottom.

Here is an example.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
    <app-root class="mb-auto"></app-root>
    <footer class="container-fluid w-100 bg-info text-light py-3">
      <div id="copyright">
        <span>xx.com is the global source of information about and access to services provided by the xxx companies.</span>
        <span class="pull-right copyright">&copy; 2019 xxxgroup Inc.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this is better than what I have, however when I scroll up or down the page, the footer keeps fixed and is always visible on top of the content. Not like header in which case you scroll down the page and header is not fixed.  I would like behavior for eg. this stackoverflow page.

Comment: nash11, Thank you very much. Saved me lot of time